# View color changing on click changes at every 8th position RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So when i click on the 0 position of recyclerview to change the color of the view it also changes the color at 8th, 16th and 24th position (i have a total of 26 items in recyclerview), if i click on position 1 it changes color at 1st, 9th, 17th and 25th and so on. how do i fix this

My recyclerview adapter is

```
public class AdapterOccupiedRoomCleaning extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterOccupiedRoomCleaning.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ItemsAdapter> mList;
    private Context mContext;

    public AdapterOccupiedRoomCleaning(List<ItemsAdapter> list, Context context){
        super();
        mList = list;
        mContext = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterOccupiedRoomCleaning.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.occupiedrooms_cleaning_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterOccupiedRoomCleaning.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        ItemsAdapter itemAdapter = mList.get(position);
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).setUrduText.setText(itemAdapter.getUrdutext());
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).setEnglishText.setText(itemAdapter.getEnglishText());
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).setCleaningImage.setImageResource(itemAdapter.getImage());
//        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).background.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//
//                //viewHolder.background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#08A467"));
//                
//                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Recycle Click " + viewHolder.setEnglishText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                viewHolder.background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#08A467"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //notifyDataSetChanged();
        return mList.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView setUrduText, setEnglishText;
        public ImageView setCleaningImage;
        public View background;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            setUrduText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.urduTextView);
            setEnglishText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.englishTextView);
            setCleaningImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageCleaning);
            background = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundColor);
        }
    }
}
```

My java class is

```
public class OccupiedRoomCleaning extends AppCompatActivity {

    String getQrCode, patientMRNO, roomNumber;
    private RecyclerView mRecycleview;
    private List<ItemsAdapter> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    private AdapterOccupiedRoomCleaning mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_occupied_room_cleaning);


        getQrCode = getIntent().getExtras().getString("qrcode");

        init();
        addList();
        adapter();
    }
    private void init(){
        mRecycleview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    }
    private void addList(){

        ItemsAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemsAdapter();
        itemAdapter.setImage(R.drawable.pillowclean);
        itemAdapter.setUrdutext("sdf");
        itemAdapter.setEnglishText("Pillow Parachute Cover Cleaning");
        mList.add(itemAdapter);

        itemAdapter = new ItemsAdapter();
        itemAdapter.setImage(R.drawable.bedclean);
        itemAdapter.setUrdutext("sdfs");
        itemAdapter.setEnglishText("Patient Bed Cleaning(Blood Spots)");
        mList.add(itemAdapter);

       //... more items




    }
    private void adapter(){
        Log.d("anhtt","mlist : " +mList.size());
        mAdapter = new AdapterOccupiedRoomCleaning(mList, this);
       
        mRecycleview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecycleview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

}
```

what am i doing wrong here that it changes color at every 8th item

Comment: i tried changing text to see if it will update the text at other positions too but it does not but when i scroll down and come back up it changes the text back to what it was before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems likely to be a problem with the view *recycling* behavior of `RecyclerView`.

Generally, you're going to run into problems like this one any time you have some property of your `ViewHolder` that you only conditionally set inside `onBindViewHolder()`. That is, because you do not **always** update the background color of your `ViewHolder`, you'll get the "wrong" color when it is recycled and reused.

You will have to somehow store the "clicked" or "selected" state in your list of items, and then update the background color of your `ViewHolder` every time in `onBindViewHolder()`. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterOccupiedRoomCleaning.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    ItemsAdapter itemAdapter = mList.get(position);
    ...

    if (itemAdapter.isSelected()) {
        viewHolder.background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#08A467"));
    } else {
        viewHolder.background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemAdapter.setSelected(true);
            viewHolder.background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#08A467"));
        }
    });
}
```

Note that it would be better to define the click listener inside `onCreateViewHolder()` and to use `notifyItemChanged()` instead of manually updating the background color, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: is isSelected() a custom method ?

Comment: Yes. You'll have to add a field to your `ItemsAdapter` class to track whether or not it has been clicked.

Comment: It might be helpful to take a step back and consider: absolutely **everything** about the `ViewHolder` should be able to be determined from the item (in your case, the `ItemsAdapter` instance) at any point in time. If the background color of your ViewHolder can change over time, then your item must provide a way to track what it "should" be. You could store a color int if it has multiple possibilities, or you could store just a `boolean` if it will only ever be e.g., black or white.

Answer (score 2):

Since, a Recycler view reuses the views and do not create new views, you need to set default color in `onBindViewHolder` function.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterOccupiedRoomCleaning.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    ItemsAdapter itemAdapter = mList.get(position);
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).setUrduText.setText(itemAdapter.getUrdutext());
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).setEnglishText.setText(itemAdapter.getEnglishText());
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).setCleaningImage.setImageResource(itemAdapter.getImage());

    // Add this line
    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("default color"));

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             viewHolder.background.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#08A467"));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this does fix the position issue but when i scroll back up color is back to the default one

Comment: you can fix this by keeping track of which items have been clicked. @BenP solution handles it